# Do two portforward rules translate to "and"?

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, port-forwarding

I just set up an Exchange server to replace my DeskNow mail server.  I want to start testing my internet mail exchange of my Exchange server.  I can only set the MX records on my DNS up to my one external IP address so I was thinking that I could set up a firewall rule on my internet-facing firewall that port forwarded the smtp packets to two different servers.

My question is:
If I do that, will that mean that the smtp packets will be forwarded to just the first internal IP on the list? Or does it mean that the packet will be cloned and sent to both IPs?

Comment: Why not simply try it and see? Should take no more than a minute of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive never seen a router do this. I'd think you would need some sort of intermediary device to either hold the mail and allow both servers to get the mail from it, ie domain pop, or to replicate it to both places. I know in Exchange to can setup rules to "redirect" the mail to a different mail server, I think this may be your best bet.